# Resuming an async read using Rx?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Another Rx question today :)

Simply put, I'm using asynchronous IO to operate on Streams. However, as we all know, we do not necessarily get all the bytes we want when using an asynchronous read - hence the return of an int on `XAsync` methods. I was wondering how could I tell an Rx `Observable` to retry a read that did not read the right amount of bytes from the Stream and offset by the correct amount?

Currently, I have this, but no idea how to set the offset parameter in ReadAsync.

```
    private IDisposable _streamMessageContract;
    private readonly byte[] _readBuffer = new byte[8024];

    public void Start()
    {
        // Subscribe to the stream for dataz
        _streamMessageContract = Observable.FromAsync<int>(() => _stream.ReadAsync(_readBuffer, 0, _readBuffer.Length))
            .Repeat()
            .Subscribe(
                y => _RawBytesReceived(_readBuffer, y),
               ex => _Exception(ex),
               () => _StreamClosed());
    }

    #region Helpers
    private void _RawBytesReceived(byte[] bytes, int actualBytesRead)
    {
    }
    private void _StreamClosed()
    {
    }
    private void _Exception(Exception e)
    {
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Syncronous streams do the exact same thing, `Read(` also returns a int showing that less than the bytes you requested could have been returned.

Comment: I would suggest you actually just keep streaming from the offset that you arrived at. e.g. If you ask for 10bytes and get back 4, you just ask for 6 more from the offset of 4. There are plenty of Rx solutions for reading from a .NET Stream. There is a basic on on IntroTo Rx - http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#CreatingYourOwnIterator, I am sure that the Rxx project has one too.

Comment: I've been reading that intro but there are a lot of words I don't understand ._.

Comment: Start at the start ;-)   Seriously tho, if something isn't clear then holla. It is supposed to easy for everyone (assuming they read it from start to finish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to just use a local variable in a closure, plus `Defer` to force the observable to re-evaluate its function on each iteration.

Assuming you want to resume reading the next block after the current block finishes, you end up with something like this...

```
// An observable that will yield the next block in the stream.
// If the resulting block length is less than blockSize, then the
// end of the stream was reached.
private IObservable<byte[]> ReadBlock(Stream stream, int blockSize)
{
    // Wrap the whole thing in Defer() so that we
    // get a new memory block each time this observable is subscribed.
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        var block = new byte[blockSize];
        int numRead = 0;
        return Observable
            .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync<int>(() =>
                stream.ReadAsync(block, numRead, block.Length - numRead)))
            .Do(y -=> numRead += y)
            .Repeat()
            .TakeWhile(y => y > 0 && numRead != blockSize) // take until EOF or entire block is read
            .LastOrDefaultAsync()  // only emit the final result of this operation
            .Select(_ =>
            {
                // If we hit EOF, then resize our result array to
                // the number of bytes actually read
                if (numRead < blockSize)
                {
                    block = block.Take(numRead).ToArray();
                }

                return block;
            });
    });
}

public void Start()
{
    // Subscribe to the stream for dataz.
    // Just keep reading blocks until
    // we get the final (under-sized) block
    _streamMessageContract = ReadBlock(stream, 8024)
        .Repeat()
        .TakeWhile(block => block.Length == 8024) // if block is small then that means we hit the end of the stream
        .Subscribe(
           block => _RawBytesReceived(block),
           ex => _Exception(ex),
           () => _StreamClosed());
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that 8024 is the *maximum sized block*, I'm not using fixed length packets, I'm using prefixed length packets, so packets vary in size.

Comment: Then call `ReadBlock` with a blocksize of 4 or whatever your prefix length size is.  Then use `SelectMany` to call `ReadBlock` again with the prefix length you just read.  Something like `ReadBlock(stream, 4).SelectMany(p => p == null ? Observable.Return<byte[]>(null) : ReadBlock(stream, BitConverter.ToInt32(p, 0)).Repeat().TakeWhile(message => message != null)`  And change ReadBlock to emit a `null` when it encounters EOF instead of emitting a smaller-sized array.

Comment: The prefix size is unknown as it's encoded in a variable-length integer (varint). That's why I currently supply a buffer of 8024 bytes and let the application decide whether or not it has read a message, and if it has, then it clears that range of bytes

Comment: Your describing what is essentially a different question.  The code I posted is an example of how to do what you originally asked, which is to resume a read operation when you did not get all of the bytes you requested.  Hopefully there's enough in there to get you going on your real problem.

Comment: I appreciate that, I was under the impression however that the answer you supplied would only work should it be able to read the full block, which is obviously not what I am looking for :P it is still the answer I needed though

Comment: My example is really just reading from the stream until it gets a full 8k block of data, which then gets passed to your callback where you can parse it however you want, if there is enough to completely decode the message, decode it.  Put any remaining un-decoded bytes somewhere, then when the next block arrives, append the new bytes to the remainder of the previous call and see if you have enough to decode a message, etc.

Comment: Well, thanks :) If I can ask one final question, I did touch on it - is it wrong of me to kind of thing of Rx observables as streams? Cus that's how I'm understanding them right now.

Comment: @DanPantry I often think of observables as streams or sequences (asynchronous ones)